# Why VS code shows it's invalid syntax for a python code using abc Module - python3.8.0

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, abc

See code below, type the same as written in Book Data Structur and Algorthm in Python, I am new to programming, can someone help?

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Sequence(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def __len__(self):


    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, j): **# Here there is red wave line under 'def'**


    def __contains__(self, val):
        for j in range(len(self)):
            if self[j] == val:
                return True
        return False

    def index(self, val):
        for j in range(len(self)):
            if self[j] == val:
                return j
        raise ValueError('value not in sequence')

    def count(self, val):
        k = 0
        for j in range(len(self)):
            if self[j] == val:
                k += 1
        return k
```

Comment: your abstract methods have no body

Comment: You need to write something in the methods; the `@abstractmethod` decorator doesn't overrule the language syntax. Do you have any examples to work from for how to use this decorator?

Comment: You might want to add at least `pass` or a docstring.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks. So if I create a abstract method, there should be sth left in the body? And docstring itself can deal as a body? I had thought that abstract method should be overwritten by subclass so I didn't have to add sth.

Answer (score 0):

In python 
Indentation is important also there is # used for comment

please go through the following code which is error-free

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Sequence(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def __len__(self):
        pass


    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, j):
        #**# Here there is red wave line under 'def'**
        pass
    def __contains__(self, val):

        for j in range(len(self)):
            if self[j] == val:
                return True
        return False

    def index(self, val):
        for j in range(len(self)):
            if self[j] == val:
                return j
        raise ValueError('value not in sequence')

    def count(self, val):
        k = 0
        for j in range(len(self)):
            if self[j] == val:
                k += 1
        return ks
```

learning python for beginning use: **learn python the hard way**
or use [python learning](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-programming-language/)